# Python Django: tzinfo doesn't work for DB insertion. But why does .now(local_tz) work?

Tags: python, django, timezone, pytz

I am using Django.

in settings:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Copenhagen'
USE_TZ = True
```

Due to DST, clock skips an hour on 2013-3-31. 01:59 goes to 03:00

I views:

The date and time are given in local time. I want these to be inserted as utc.

Code below correctly saves as UTC, but gives RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime

```
the_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 31, 1, 59)
hit = hits(date= the_date); hit.save(); # Correctly saved as 00:59:00

the_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 31, 3, 1)
hit = hits(date= the_date); hit.save(); # Correctly saved as 01:01:00
```

I thought I could avoid the warning by making the datetime aware. It does avoid the warning, but the conversion is now wrong.

```
tz = timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
the_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 31, 3, 1, tzinfo = tz)
hit = hits(date= the_date); hit.save(); # Incorrectly saved as 02:01:00
```

The following works, with no runtime error:

```
I have installed pytz.
the_date = local_tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 31, 3, 1))
```

Getting to my question:

I get that tzinfo doesn't work because it doesn't account for daylight savings time. Fine, I won't use it. But then I was confused when the following seemed to work:

```
the_date = datetime.datetime.now(local_tz)
```

This correctly inserted as utc both in wintertime (where it subtracted 1 hour to get utc) and when I changed my computer systime to a date in the summer (where it subtracted 2 hours to get utc).

My question:

Does .now(local_tz) work or did I test it wrong? Why is this different than tzinfo = tz? Or am I using tzinfo wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend converting to UTC as soon as possible and only use UTC internally. Save for cases where you move across timezones (for example a marine vessel) and really need to save timezone information, for the constant timezone case, it's much simpler to just use local time for input/output and convert it to UTC at the user interface.

To convert from localtime to UTC, you need to use the `pytz.timezone.normalize` method which handles daylight savings time and other timezone transition. See this [section of the `pytz` documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#problems-with-localtime). In your case, to convert the local datetime to UTC you need the following:

```
from pytz import timezone, utc

local_tz = timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
local_dt = datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 31, 3, 1, tzinfo = local_tz)
utc_dt = utc.normalize(local_dt.astimezone(utc))
```

Comment: It also works with localize(), including dst. I can insert fine (at least I think so). The question is why does datetime.now(local_tz) work when setting tzinfo doesn't? Can I use  datetime.now(local_tz) just like that. (I'd be curious to see an example where normalize works, but localize doesn't, but that's really for another question...)

Comment: It seems there are cases where `normalize` is really necessary, although I can't give you an example right now. I'll leave the answer for reference. Anyway if your timezone is constant I really recommend always using UTC internally and only convert from/to localtime for input/output: it will save you some headaches.

Comment: Yes, I agree to use utc whenever possible. But what I really want is to understand these things, not just have one way that works. And this is something that I don't understand. (I am sometimes given dates in local time. I need to deal with these.)

Comment: I can only support and agree with your need to understand how things work! Good luck with your research, let us know if you find something interesting. :)